# Why have people stopped voting?

Tags: discussion, participation, voting, site-stats, users

We have hit another ***all-time*** weekly low in voting:

[image]

- Previously in the week of Sunday April 10 2022 we had an all-time low of 106 votes on the main site.
- Recently in the week of Sunday August 21 2022 we have hit a new all-time low of 96 votes on the main site.

It's easy to see who these people are (e.g. they're answering questions or commenting on posts but the post still has 0 upvotes and 0 downvotes, even though they weren't doing that last year; or simply they've fallen down in the [voter rankings](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all)). But rather than calling anyone specific out, perhaps we can get opinions from the entire community in a Meta thread (i.e. this one)!